# Connect Amazon RDS with database

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am new to Amazon RDS. I have much confusions about this service and could not got any reasonable stuff on internet even on Amazon website.

I want to know that I have a web application having database. How can I connect my database with Amazon RDS service. Tutorials on amazon website have not much information. I want step by step tutorial, but could not found any on internet.

Can I connect Amazon RDS with my webapp's local database too?

Comment: have you configured `RDS`?

Comment: yes i have configured it.

Comment: then now what is the problem?

Comment: i have configured it on Amazon console. Now i want to connect it with my sql databse.   @PathikVejani can i chat with you on skype . . .i have more questions to . . . to be cleared

Comment: Ok. let me make steps.

Comment: ok  . . i am waiting for your steps. .

Comment: did you give a try ?

Comment: @PathikVejani No, i just have left it for the time being as our project moved to firebase. I will cosider it later. Thanks for your co-operation.

Comment: Just to clear concept. . . in your last step 4) Final step: change in your DB config file: 'localhost' to that 'mydbinstance.casdv4nzvleb.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com'. . . if i am not wrong ..you are changing database path from localhost to rds. . .if so then let me clear i want lacal database working. . .with sync functionality to rds.

Comment: It will work.. and also it will sync to RDS. no worries.

Answer (score 0):

After logged into Amazon Account, Steps to connect RDS:

```
1) From the dashboard, Select RDS Dashboard, Here you can see the RDS instance
2) Select instance and copy Endpoint string
3) Now go to `/etc/phpmyadmin` and open `config.inc.php` file, change in that file to the endpoint which we have copied. Like below: <br>
<?php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    /* Server parameters */
    if (empty($dbserver)) $dbserver = 'mydbinstance.casdv4nzvleb.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $dbserver;
?>

4) Final step: change in your DB config file: 'localhost' to that 'mydbinstance.casdv4nzvleb.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
```

First show me your **Endpoint**. 
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Currently i am working using testing account so . . .  mydbinstance.casdv4nzvleb.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306

Comment: use this `mydbinstance.casdv4nzvleb.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`

Comment: after completing all the steps, restart the MySQL server and apache2

Comment: i am working using simple HTML and JavaScript. I am sorry . . i am confused . . . . I Want to connect using Javascript.

Comment: I am new to web technology. So taking time to understand whats going on. so dont mind please.

Comment: What do you mean by connect using javascript?

Comment: Sorry i could not reply fast as i was researching. . . http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/php/. . . amazon provided functionality to access databaseinstance by php, ios java, node.js blah blah blah. . . i was wondering for functionality by simple javascript. . .but only found this. . . .http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/browser/

Comment: @Zeebok i don't think it is related to you

Comment: You have to create php file and then connect to RDS database